# HTML text decoration on half a sentence?

Tags: html

I was wondering how I could put a text-decoration in a specific part of a `<li>` instead of the entire sentence. Here's a code snippet.

```html
<ul>
<li>I'm a List item!</li>
<li style="text-decoration:line-through">From Here til here should have a line through, not these words</li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Break the text in two spans, each one of them having different styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another element. Apply the style to that element.

```css
span {
  text-decoration: line-through
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>I'm a List item!</li>
  <li><span>From Here til here should have a line through,</span> not these words</li>
```

… which element you choose will depend on *why* you want the line through. `<del>` might be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```css
span {
  text-decoration: line-through
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>I'm a List item!</li>
  <li>From Here til here should have a <span>line through</span>, not these words</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to wrap it in another element. The `span` element is commonly used for this:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>I'm a List item!</li>
    <li class="half-line"><span>From Here til here should have a line through,</span> not these words</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.half-line span {
    text-decoration: line-through
}
```

This will apply the `text-decoration` property to any `span` elements inside of your `.half-line` class only.